# Expect conditionals don't seem to be working

Tags: bash, expect

Edit: Everything works perfectly without the conditional. Adding in the conditional breaks the script. I've tried conditionals in other simpler scripts and those have worked.

Edit2: Adding the full script as other instances of expect conditionals have worked

I'm trying to modify an autoexpect generated expect script that works when the build succeeds but doesn't handle the build failing.

After significant research, I can't figure out why my expect conditional isn't working

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set force_conservative 0  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
                          ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
        set send_slow {1 .1}
        proc send {ignore arg} {
                sleep .1
                exp_send -s -- $arg
        }
}

set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
expect "~\$ "
send -- "sudo su\r"
expect "/home/ubuntu# "
send -- "cd ../../opt/application/"
send -- "\r"
expect  "/opt/application# "
send -- "./buildwar.sh \r"
expect  {
        "BUILD SUCCESSFUL\r" {
                send -- "su appuser\r"
                expect  "/opt/application\$ "
                send -- "../../home/ubuntu/shutdown.sh \r"
                expect  "\"outcome\" => \"success\"}"
                send -- "exit\r"
                expect "/opt/application# "
                send -- "./deploywar.sh \r"
                expect "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"
                send -- "su appuser\r"
                expect  "/opt/application\$ "
                send -- "../../home/ubuntu/startup.sh \r"
                expect "Deployed \"application.war\""
                send -- "exit\r"
                send -- "exit\r"
                send -- "exit\r"
                exit 0
        }

        "BUILD FAILED\r" {
                exit 1
        }
}
```

Comment: You `exit 1` on success?

Comment: @chrisaycock Yep - this way the shell script that calls this expect script can continue with it's other responsibilities

Comment: @General_Twyckenham: the stress was on `1`. Why do you return with an error?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I wasn't aware that exit was an error - I thought it was just an end-of-script command with a status code

Comment: any non-zero status code is considered an error.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Either way - as far as I can tell, it's not even hitting there as it doesn't seem to enter that code block (ie. doesn't match `"BUILD SUCESSFUL \r"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that nesting `expect` statements doesn't seem to work, so instead of the posted code, the following works:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set force_conservative 0  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
                          ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
        set send_slow {1 .1}
        proc send {ignore arg} {
                sleep .1
                exp_send -s -- $arg
        }
}

set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
expect "~\$ "
send -- "sudo su\r"
expect "/home/ubuntu# "
send -- "cd ../../opt/application/"
send -- "\r"
expect  "/opt/application# "
send -- "./buildwar.sh \r"
expect  {
        "BUILD SUCCESSFUL\r" {
                send -- "su appuser\r"
        }

        "BUILD FAILED\r" {
                exit 1
        }
}
expect  "/opt/application\$ "
send -- "../../home/ubuntu/shutdown.sh \r"
expect  "\"outcome\" => \"success\"}"
send -- "exit\r"
expect "/opt/application# "
send -- "./deploywar.sh \r"
expect "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"
send -- "su appuser\r"
expect  "/opt/application\$ "
send -- "../../home/ubuntu/startup.sh \r"
expect "Deployed \"application.war\""
send -- "exit\r"
send -- "exit\r"
send -- "exit\r"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to run with expect debugging on (`expect -d`). You don't actually show what data you are expecting.

It works for me:

```
$ expect -c '
  log_user 0
  spawn sh -c {echo "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"}
  expect {
          "BUILD SUCCESSFUL\r" {
                  #various and sundry other code to run
                  exit 123
          }

          "BUILD FAILED\r" {
                  exit 56
          }
  }
'
$ echo $?
123
```

```
$ expect -c '
  log_user 0
  spawn sh -c {echo "BUILD FAILED"}
  expect {
          "BUILD SUCCESSFUL\r" {
                  #various and sundry other code to run
                  exit 123
          }

          "BUILD FAILED\r" {
                  exit 56
          }
  }
'
$ echo $?
56
```

Comment: Oh cool that's really useful. The data I'm looking for is precisely `"BUILD SUCCESSFUL\r"` (after a whole slew of other comments being logged). After running with the -d flag, it looks like the conditional expect line isn't being understood as a command - it's not checking the outputs at that point

Answer (score 1):

You need to match against `\n` - though it won't matter if you just omit it.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure I understand your answer. Where am I adding `\n`?

Comment: here: `"BUILD SUCCESSFUL\n"`

Comment: That did not work. As I said earlier, the script matches `"BUILD SUCCESSFUL \r"` perfectly when not attempting a conditional, so I doubted the `\n` would change anything

Comment: This works here under Linux, and I don't see why a newline should be matched with `\r`. Maybe there's some additional white space at the end of the line.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the point - the same text that gets matched without the conditional is missed with the conditional. Literally the only thing changing is whether `"BUILD SUCCESSFUL\r"` is inside the brace or if it comes right after `expect`. The text to match isn't the problem

Comment: You mean that code from the second snippet worked for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92890/discussion-between-general-twyckenham-and-yacc).